# Showing 'Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from TestExample.jar'

Tags: java, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from TestExample.jar
```

How to resolve the above problem of when I  am trying to run the executable jar file?

Comment: Are you creating your jar from command prompt?

Comment: are you able to find any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the `META-INF` file in the jar which specifies the `Main-Class` ?

Command: `jar cvfm MyJarName.jar manifest.txt *.class`

cvfm means "create a jar; show verbose output; specify the output jar file name; specify the manifest file name."

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the main class in the Manifest. This is how you specify the entry point into the jar. The class you specify here needs to have a main method which is executed first when running the jar.

Take a look at this for a good explanation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 0):

Java has two methods to start with a JAR file. The first one specifies the JAR file and the main class (the class with the static `main(String[])` method):

```
java -cp .../example.jar com.example.Main
```

The second method uses the `-jar` parameter (instead of the `-classpath` parameter). It does NOT allow to specify the main class: instead it expects the main class to be specifies inside of the JAR file in the [Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main_Attributes). (`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` containing a line `Main-Class: com.example.Main`).

```
java -jar example.jar
```

Your Error message means you have a JAR file which is not constructed as an executable JAR file (no manifest entry for the main class). You either need to build the JAR differently or start it with the first variant of the command line. BTW: the second variant is often used when you double click a file with the `*.jar` file extension.